Robot localization, Navsat, and IMU inconsistencies
I've spent a long time on Rep103, the standards for pose, and the expectations of robot localization, ekf_filter_node, and the navsat_transform. I'm writing for help in understanding the various conventions and expectations. Basically, I'm looking for best practices in writing an IMU driver - there are ambiguities that I do not know how to deal with.
1/ Per Rep 103, the body orientation standard is X forwards, Y left, and Z up. This applies to position, velocities, twists, and data from wheel sensors as well as IMUs etc. In addition, the right hand rule applies. In particular:

Rotation about the y axis (pitch) is positive in the nose down direction
Rotation about the x axis (roll) is positive for right side down motion
Rotation about the z axis (yaw) is positive for CCW rotation (flipped compared to the normal convention where turning the airplane right increases the heading)

So far, so good. Based on that, it's possible to write an IMU driver for linear accelerations and angular velocity that conforms to those standards. And, I can take the accel, gyro, and mag data and compute a north-facing orientation quarterion.
2/ HOWEVER, navsat_transform expects IMU data in ENU, in particular, when the robot is pointing East, the orientation quarterion is (0,0,0,1). Ok, so now I can take the orientation quarterion and transform it to ENU:
// Rotate data to match ENU convention
tf::Quaternion quat(curr_ahrs_quaternion_.q[1], curr_ahrs_quaternion_.q[2], curr_ahrs_quaternion_.q[3], curr_ahrs_quaternion_.q[0]);
tf::Quaternion rotX = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(M_PI, 0, 0);
tf::Quaternion rotZ = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(0, 0, -M_PI/2);
tf::Quaternion quat_rotated = rotX * rotZ * quat;   

3/ Now, of course, the Orientation quarterion is no longer axis consistent with the raw linear accelerations and angular velocities. No problem, I can hack things throughout the ROS2 codebase to make everything work, for example careful choice of ekf settings, messing around with transforms, and use of the navsat yaw offset parameter, but that seems very messy. QUESTION: When writing a "standards" compliant IMU driver that conforms with all current ROS2 standards, from odometry, pose, IMU, and navsat, what does that driver look like?
The gaol is to end up with a driver that (1) is standards compliant, thereby allowing (2) all ROS2 packages and nodes to work out of the box, with resorting to strange hacks (such as the navsat yaw offset parameter). Any guidance would be appreciated.
